# How to add [ ] brackets to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, regex, string, object

I actually receive this format of JSON format:

```
{ "bank": "CityBank", "sum": "500" }, { "bank": "WPBank", "sum": "700" }
```

But is can't be parsed without [] brackets. The result should be:

```
[{ "bank": "CityBank", "sum": "500" }, { "bank": "WPBank", "sum": "700" }]
```

How to add these brackets in JS?

Comment: Where are you getting the broken JSON from?  The problem should be fixed at the source. The first sample simply is not JSON.

Comment: The former is not JSON. Recommended way would be to correct the API from where you get such response.

Comment: `let parsed = JSON.parse(\`[${notJSON}]\`);`

Comment: How does this even come back from a response? Usually if there's invalid JSON, nothing comes back at all.

Comment: @Scrimothy - clearly the API returns text - which can be anything, even not JSON :p

Comment: @JaromandaX ah yes. good point

Comment: Of course, if the API purports to return JSON, and returns that instead, then, as the first 2 comments suggest, the API needs fixin' @Scrimothy

Comment: Well, first it returned me a messy JSON with "/n/r" this kind of symbol, so i had to replace and correct all of this, not sure maybe the reason is in bad serializer. Anyway, i'll try your approaches and let you know about results.

Comment: It depends how you see the response. I know for a fact that [Elasticsearch also works with strange JSON input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-batch-processing.html) (I'm not sure about the output). However if you replaced the newlines with commas you might want to reconsider the approach. I'm guessing that every line needs to be parsed on itself. Instead of the whole thing at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just take the invalid JSON and parse correctly it using `JSON.parse`:

```js
let invalid = '{ "bank": "CityBank", "sum": "500" }, { "bank": "WPBank", "sum": "700" }';
let valid = JSON.parse("[" + invalid + "]");
console.log(valid);
```

Comment: This is cool-- I didn't know that `JSON.parse` could work around invalid JSON.  What are the limits on this?  Is there some known degree/manner that input can be malformed at which `JSON.parse` will fail?

Comment: No, `JSON.parse` above is *not* parsing invalid JSON - it's parsing an invalid JSON string which I have concatenated into a valid JSON string by adding square brackets.

Comment: No problem @AlexanderNied, always glad to help.